# Solving Trigonometric Derivatives

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

I have a function $F(θ) = \sin^{−1} \sqrt{\sin(11θ)}$

I derived the following answer using basic trigonometric and quotient rules.

$\dfrac{11\csc \left(\left(11\theta \right)^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right)\cos \left(\left(11\theta \right)\right)}{2\sqrt{1-\sin \left(11\theta \right)}}$

My answer however is wrong.

Can anyone outline how to go about getting the correct solution to a problem such as this?

Comment: Thank you for the corrections Arnaldo

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. By using the chain rule and standard derivatives, one has
$$
\begin{align}
F'(θ) &= \left(\sin^{−1} \sqrt{\sin(11θ)}\right)'
\\\\&= \color{red}{\left(\sqrt{\sin(11θ)}\right)'}\cdot \left.\left(\sin^{−1}u\right)' \right|_{u=\sqrt{\sin(11θ)}}
\\\\&= \color{red}{\left(\sin(11θ)\right)'\cdot \frac1{2\sqrt{\sin(11θ)}}}\cdot \frac1{\sqrt{1-\left(\sqrt{\sin(11θ)}\right)^2}}
\end{align}
$$ Hope you can finish it.

Comment: I am lost with this answer. Even looking at the trigonometric rules I cannot see how you got the second expression in the first evaluation.

Comment: To Donnie: With $f(t)=\sin^{-1)(t)$ and $g(t)= \sqrt {\sin 11t}$ we have $F'(x)=(f(g(x))'=f'(g(x)\cdot g'(x).$... And put $  t=g(x)-\sqrt {\sin 11x}$ into the equation $f'(t)=(\sin^{-1}t)'=1/\sqrt {1-t^2}$ to evaluate $f'(g(x)).$

Answer (score 0):

We have $\sin F(x)= (\sin 11x)^{1/2}.$ so by the Chain Rule, $$(1)....(\cos F(x)\;)\cdot F'(x)=(1/2)(\sin 11x)^{(1/2-1)})(11\cos 11 x)=\frac {11\cos 11x}{2\sqrt {\sin 11x}}.$$  Assuming that we are using the  main (or usual) branch of $\sin^{-1}$, which takes values in $[-\pi /2,\pi /2],$ we have $F(x)\in [-\pi /2,\pi /2]$ so $\cos F(x)\geq 0$.

So $$\cos F(x)=\sqrt {1-\sin^2F(x)}=\sqrt {1-\sin 11x}$$ which we can substitute  into (1).